# Piano piece from Jay Chou movie

Tags: identify-this-song, piano

https://youtu.be/wjiA1iPMjE4?t=51m44s

This is a movie from Jay Chou, in which he writes his own music to use for the movie. However, I'm unsure if this piano piece in the link above is written by him or some other artist because I am unable to find it anywhere, therefore asking it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely in the style of Chopin, but I don't recognize it as Chopin.

The [soundtrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_(soundtrack)) only lists one Chopin piece (Op. 10, No. 5) as part of a ["piano battle,"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNUzJ2rhw2k) but this isn't that piece.

All this to say I'd guess it's an original composition by Chou.